# Redirecting to permanently moved page with response code 302

Tags: c, http

I am sending this request from my C code:

```
char * request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" \
"Host: www.some.com\r\n" \
"Connection: keep-alive\r\n" \
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36\r\n" \
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n\r\n";
```

But I get this response after sending the above request:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://www.some.com/?gws_rd=ssl
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
BFCache-Opt-In: unload
Date: Thu, 24 Feb 2022 06:17:10 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 231
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2022-02-24-06; expires=Sat, 26-Mar-2022 06:17:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.some.com; Secure; SameSite=none

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.some.com/?gws_rd=ssl">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

This is the message `<A HREF="https://www.some.com/?gws_rd=ssl">here</A>.` so If I follow https://www.some.com/?gws_rd=ssl I dont get any data, its like request is being sent but data is not received. I sending this request to https://www.some.com/?gws_rd=ssl

```
  char *x="GET / https://www.some.com/?gws_rd=ssl\r\n\r\n";
```

why is that. Whats wrong with my http/https.

I am using openSSL.

So after sending initial request the server moved the resource to new url. Now when I following the new url nothing happens no data response

Code:

```
/* filename nossl.c */
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/bio.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

int main()
{
    BIO * bio;
    char resp[1024];
    int  ret;

    //char * request = "GET /cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.corp.ema-tech.com%3A8888%2F HTTP/1.1\x0D\x0AHost: web.corp.ema-tech.com\x0D\x0A\x43onnection: Close\x0D\x0A\x0D\x0A";
    char * request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" \
"Host: www.yoursite.com\r\n" \
"Connection: keep-alive\r\n" \
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36\r\n" \
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n\r\n";
char *x="GET / https://www.yoursite.com/?gws_rd=ssl\r\n\r\n";
    /* Set up the library */
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    /* Create and setup the connection */
    //bio = BIO_new_connect("web.corp.ema-tech.com:8888");
    printf("___________________________+\n");
    bio = BIO_new_connect("www.yoursite.com:80");

    if(bio == NULL) {
    printf("====___________________________-\n");
        printf("BIO is null\n");

    }

    if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0) {
     printf("+++++___________________________@\n");

        BIO_free_all(bio);

    }
printf("___________________________@^\n");

    /* Send the request */
    BIO_write(bio, request, strlen(request));
printf("___________________________0\n");
    /* Read in the response */
    for(;;) {
        ret = BIO_read(bio, resp, 1023);
        printf("----%d\n",ret);
        if(ret <= 0) break;
        resp[ret] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", resp);
    }
    BIO_write(bio,x,sizeof("GET / https://www.yoursite.com/?gws_rd=ssl\r\n\r\n"));
    for(;;) {
            ret = BIO_read(bio, resp, 1023);
            printf("----%d\n",ret);
            if(ret <= 0) break;
            resp[ret] = 0;
            printf("%s\n", resp);
        }
    /* Close the connection and free the context */
    BIO_free_all(bio);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Send a request to path `/?gws_rd=ssl` not the full `https` path.

Comment: HTTP and all related dialects, extensions and encodings are sufficiently numerous and complex that I recommend anyone to use a library for that. Even for simple tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first request was HTTP (not HTTPS) then the server is mainly telling you to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. Your request would be

```
char * request = "GET /?gws_rd=ssl HTTP/1.1\r\n" \ 
                 "Host: www.some.com\r\n" ...
```

The /?gws_rd=ssl is the local resource name (/) and a query string (?gws_rd=ssl) from https://www.some.com/?gws_rd=ssl, while the host name [www.some.com](http://www.some.com) goes to the "Host:" header.
Some servers will only allow to connect if you are using the server name TLS extension (OpenSSL: "SSL_set_tlsext_host_name") and supply the host name as well.

You could also think about using an C existing library for a HTTPS client, for example:

- libcurl (https://curl.se/libcurl/ - libcurl is one of the most used HTTP/HTTPS client libraries in C)
- CivetWeb (https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb/blob/master/docs/api/mg_connect_client_secure.md - actually a server with some additional client functions; disclaimer: I am in the maintainer team of this server).

Both are open source and MIT licensed.

Edit:

> Actually I need to know difference between openssl and https

HTTPS is a communication protocol (HyperText Transfer Protocol Secure).
OpenSSL is a crypto library.

The protocol stack from HTTP like:

```
HTTP:   [HTTP]
        [TCP/IP]
```

The stack from HTTPS looks like:

```
HTTPS:   [HTTP]
         [TLS (= SSL)]
         [TCP/IP]
```

SSL stands for Secure Sockets Layer, and TLS (Transport Layer Security) is the successor of SSL. OpenSSL implements SSL version 2 and 3 (both deprecated) as well as all versions of TLS (1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3).
OpenSSL can provide the middle part of the HTTPS stack, but you still need the top and bottom part. They are identical to HTTP, so TLS (the protocol) respectively OpenSSL (a library implementing the protocol) is inserted in the middle.

To see this live in action try to read from [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) using the OpenSSL command line:

```
$ openssl s_client www.google.com
```

The server will provide some information, in particular the server certificate. Then you type:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Connection: close
```

After the empty line at the bottom, the server will send a header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: ..
Server: gws
Connection: close
```

Followed by an empty line and finally a HTML page.

This OpenSSL command line client will implement the TLS layer and use the TCP/IP layer from the operating system. But you have to provide the HTTP layer on top: The four lines of text (GET ..., Host ..., Connection ... and the empty line at the end) is a valid HTTP protocol request.

The full source of s_client can be found here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/s_client.c
The source is lengthy because it provides a hundred different options.

A much smaller client example with more explanation can be found here:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client
You will find the same four lines for the HTTP protocol in this example:

```
BIO_puts(web, "GET " HOST_RESOURCE " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
              "Host: " HOST_NAME "\r\n"
              "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

In your code you used "Connection: keep-alive". That's perfectly fine if you want to make multiple HTTP requests using the same HTTP connection. Just make sure the last request you want to make used "Connection: close". Also be aware that a HTTP server may decide to close the connection at any time by sending a "Connection: close" header.
"Connection: close" is easier to begin with.

If you only want to download a web page, these four lines of code are usually enough - unless you need a login/cookies/access token/... for a specific web site. Additional requests such as POST (e.g, submitting a web form) will require more lines on top of OpenSSL. If you need this, you should consider using an additional library instead of implementing it on your own.

The response of the server needs to be split into header (everything above the first empty line) and body (everything below). Depending on the header, it might be required to interpret the body data differently.
For example, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) will send one header line "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" (instead of "Content-Length: ####"). This are two different ways a server can let the client know how long the body data is supposed to be. If you get a "Content-Length: 1234" header, you know that you have to read 1234 bytes in your HTTP protocol implementation.
If you get a "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header, the server will first send a hex number, followed by "\r\n". Followed by as many bytes as the hex number stated before. Followed by another hex number, "\r\n" and more data. Finally a hex number "0" will indicate the end of the data. The hex numbers and "\r\n" are not part of the HTML page - you need to remove it (if you keep it, you will end up with broken HTML or whatever you want to download).
If a server neither sends "Content-Length:" nor "Transfer-Encoding:" then you need to read until the server closes the connection.
This is also part of the HTTP protocol hat has to be implemented on top of OpenSSL for a HTTPS client. You will have to implement all three in a HTTP or HTTPS client, unless you need to communicate with only one server and you know it is only using "Content-Length: ####".

Comment: Actually I need to know difference between openssl and https. I am using openssl and assuming that this will fetch my https page from let say google.com main page. Now can u elaborate on this mixture of understand. I am mixing that use of openssl is enough to fetch https page that is present at `https://www.Google.com`. any thing on this